# Large study showing that attraction to only the same sex has to do with your genes, published where?

Tags: genetics, database, sex, sexual-selection, sex-chromosome

Can someone please help me out and find and link me the study from a couple of years ago that showed how only same sex attraction, when the male cant become attracted to a woman, it has to do with genes?, it was a large study and a first of its kind, maybe from 2016-2019, i am not talking about the big study from 2018 by Andrea Ganna about not finding any single gene that explains sexual orientation.

Comment: Is it this? https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-15736-4

Comment: @AlexReynolds That seems more like an answer than a comment.

Comment: No thats not the one. They said that it was the largest study of its kind, and i think they might have mention DNA besides the word genes also but i am not sure, i know it was a very big studie that looked at genes/DNA in a new way. It seems like not many places wrote about it and then the other study by Andrea Ganna came and everybody wrote about that so its hard to find it now i have looked a long time.

Comment: Have you looked at the references section in the Ganna study? If this is as large a study as you say, it may well be referenced there, and the date range may help you drill down to what you're after.

Comment: Nope its not there, i think the both studies where done very close in time and thats why. Only the Ganna study got any real news.

Comment: I'd suggest scanning the reference sections of as many related papers as you can. You have a known time window to limit your search to some reasonable possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly https://science.sciencemag.org/content/365/6456/eaat7693.long is what you were looking for?  It implicates a few specific genes - the connection to olfaction is interesting (I would suggest it could be fun to look up the vomeronasal organ, terminal nerve, and GnRH).  [Alex Reynolds' suggestion of https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-15736-4 is highly useful for those reading, even if it wasn't what you were looking for.  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0091302219300585?via%3Dihub is also potentially useful]